# bug: "consecutive visit counter" reset

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

My consecutive visits were at 76 yesterday, then this morning it is back to 1? Is there a way to get this corrected? What forum is the correct one to ask this question? (I do not have access to chat at work).

Comment: Could you have missed the 24 hour window? I believe the consecutive visits are calculated by calendar date according to UTC. So, if you are timezone-shifted enough off of UTC, it would be possible to visit the site every single calendar date, and yet miss a UTC-day.

Comment: well .... &#$% . Any recourse?

Comment: @RoryAlsop This is fine here. There's no need to move such reports to meta.so.

Answer (score 3):

On Sunday, you only made one single request to the site, which was to the homepage. This [doesn't count as a meaningful access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126633/115866) to the site for the consecutive days counter.

I've made an exception and set the day as "visited" for you this one time, but note that the system was behaving as expected.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know what constitutes meaningful access. I did not know. And thank you for resetting my counter. I know it must seem petty, but I've been trying to get to 100 since I joined, and it keeps resetting. Now I know why.

Comment: Oh, don't worry; you're not alone by far! :)